# Lexical analysis of data structure of different delimiters

Tags: parsing, data-structures, lexical-analysis

I'm making a lexer and a parser to parse one data format to another (partly as an exercise), and I have a question:

Let's say we have 3 different data types, and these data types are identified by their delimiters:

1. a|b  #we'll call this type "segments"
2. a~b  #we'll call this type "array"
3. a^b  #we'll call this type "components"

You can also mix them like this:

```
hey~there|how~are~you
```

which would correspond to something like this in pseudo-code:

```
[["hey", "there"], ["how", "are", you"]]
```

and

```
hey~there^you~guy|hi|hehe
```

which would correspond to:

```
[[["hey", "there"], ["you", "guy"]], "hi", "hehe"]
```

Now my question is, in my lexer do I look ahead to see what type of data we're dealing with so that I can emit the token type first before all the strings and delimiters get emitted? Or do I make the parser try to figure it out by the delimiter tokens it gets?

Example for `hey~there^you~guy|hi|hehe`:

```
(segment)
(component)
(array)
(string "hey")
(array_delim "~")
(string "there")
(component_delim "^")
(component)
(array)
(string "you")
(array_delim "~")
(string "guy")
(segment_delim "|")
(string "hi")
(segment_delim "|")
(string "hehe")
```

versus

```
(string "hey")
(array_delim "~")
(string "there")
(component_delim "^")
(string "you")
(array_delim "~")
(string "guy")
(segment_delim "|")
(string "hi")
(segment_delim "|")
(string "hehe")
```

In the first case the parser would know a component or array is coming, and make the right data structures ahead of time. In the second example it would kind of have to backtrack what it did, since it figures out what data structure it is later.

Comment: In the first case, you need the lexer to contain a separate parser as well, which kinds of defeat the purpose of having a "separate" parsing step. Also, if you are using a parser-generator then the second option is much easier to write a parser for (not to mention the lexer becomes _much_ simpler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the second example is really what you want to use. From the looks of it your syntax has the following precedence.

```
segments = 0
components = 1
array = 2
```

With that in mind you can implement an [Operator-precedence parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser). Which would process your tokens like this:

```
shift (string "hey")
shift (array_delim "~")
shift (string "there")
reduce array1
shift array1
shift (component_delim "^") 
shift (string "you")
shift (array_delim "~")
shift  (string "guy")
reduce array2
reduce component1 
shift component1 
shift (segment_delim "|")
shift (string "hi")
reduce segment1 
shift segment1 
shift (segment_delim "|") 
shift (string "hehe")
reduce segment2
done
```

This will result in a parse tree like this.

```
segment
    segment
        component
            array
                string(hey)
                string(there)
            array
                string(you)
                string(guy)
        string(hi)
    string(hehe)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I did it a bit differently, but basically followed this and the guidlines from: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift-reduce_parser), [link](http://dragonbook.stanford.edu/lecture-notes/Stanford-CS143/08-Bottom-Up-Parsing.pdf). Thank you!

Comment: @kdar - I'm glad to hear it. Don't you just love algorithms?